# how to add an attachment to the sendEmail quickaction apI through lightning component?

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

```
i need to populate the attachment on send email lightning quick action api. i can able to set the 
subject to the email quick action, but i need to add the attachment to the email. How can i send the
```

attachment from apex to lightning component 
how to return the attachment from apex to lightning component. and how to add to HtmlBody parameter for lightning quick action api?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to attach using this it might help you:

```
var actionAPI = component.find("quickActionAPI");
    //var targetFields = {Subject:{value:"Sets by lightning:quickActionAPI component 3"}, HtmlBody:{value:'HTML BODY'}};
    var targetFields = {
        Subject:{
            value:"Sets by lightning:quickActionAPI component"
        }, 
        HtmlBody:{
            value:'HTML BODY'
        },
        ToAddress:{
            value:'devid@testgmail.com'
        },
        ContentDocumentIds:{
            value:['0691D000001cgXXXX']
        }
    };
    var args = {actionName: "Quote.SendEmail", entityName: "Quote", targetFields: targetFields};
    
    actionAPI.getAvailableActions(args).then(function(result){
        //All available action fields shown for Log a Call
        console.log('##getAvailableActions#result==', JSON.stringify(result));
    }).catch(function(e){
        
        console.error(e.errors);
        if(e.errors){
            //If the specified action isn't found on the page, show an error message in the my component 
        }
    });
    
    actionAPI.getAvailableActionFields(args).then(function(result){
        //All available action fields shown for Log a Call
        console.log('##getAvailableActionFields#result==', JSON.stringify(result));
    }).catch(function(e){
        
        console.error(e.errors);
        if(e.errors){
            //If the specified action isn't found on the page, show an error message in the my component 
        }
    });
    
    actionAPI.setActionFieldValues(args).then(function(response){
        console.log('##WORKING#setActionFieldValues##', response, args);
        //actionAPI.invokeAction(args);
        console.log('##WORKING#setActionFieldValues##');
    }).catch(function(e){
        console.error(e.errors);
    });
```

More methods available here please check: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/quickaction_api.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need do as follows
1. Create Lightning Flow action to trigger Apex code.
2. Using apex code trigger email and attach attachments also.